# Migration of source code from one collection to another

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

I have installed the TFS integration tool and tried to migrate source code from one collection to another on same server. It is working and it copied the code with history to new collection however the history which it is showing is check-in by single user which is mine as I have migrated:

- This was the history of one file before migration
  [image]
- This is the history after migration, in this the changeset numbers are changed and the date is also changed.  Old Changeset information of number, date and checkin is given in brackets. 
  [image]
- If we right click on any changeset and select changeset details than it shows the complete information  as shown:
  [image]

As this migration gives a new changeset number all over previous linking of workitems with changesets will be lost.
Am I doing it right or there is any other way to do it? Can I get the same history as that was in previous collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TFS migration tool is great, but still has some limitations. For example, it is not possible to keep the date of the original checkin and the changesetnumber will not be the same. It is possible to keep the changeset number the same. To achieve this, activate the user mapping feature as described in http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2010/11/tfs-to-tfs-migration-between-two-domains/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answere however that link is showing the migration between two different domain. In my case the domain is same what i want is the history to be remained same as it was before

Comment: That link is just an example what shows is possible, but as mentioned, you cannot keep the history the same using the TFS migration tools.